# How to change NOCOUNT setting within LinqToSQL because of ChangeConflictException in Linq to Sql update

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am experiencing *exactly* this problem (and am in exactly the same world of pain):
[ChangeConflictException in Linq to Sql update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663822/changeconflictexception-in-linq-to-sql-update)

Whereby I am offering an update to SQL using LinqToSQL and it is failing with a `ChangeConflictException` because `NOCOUNT` is set to `ON`.

Due to legacy databases also on the server I am targeting, I am not able to re-configure the default connection settings as is quite rightly stated in the accepted answer in [ChangeConflictException in Linq to Sql update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663822/changeconflictexception-in-linq-to-sql-update/757276#757276).

My question is: How do you convince LinqToSQL to run a SQL `SET NOCOUNT OFF` before executing an update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a trick.

You can use ExecuteQuery method (from DataContext object) to execute something like `ExecuteQuery<int>("SET NOCOUNT OFF SELECT 1");`
and after that you can set the new property/properties for your object(the one you wanted to update) and call SubmitChanges().