# Byte type of field column not updating in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

One column named Favorite(tinyint) in table of "Products" in sql server. I have generated entity it is converted into entity as looking like,

```
public class Products
{
   ----- Other Fields ------
    public byte Favorite { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to update entity as by given code below,

```
 using (ADataContext dataContext = new ADataContext())
 {

     var product = dataContext.Products.Where(p => p.Id == 10).FirstOrDefault();
     product.Favorite = (byte)EnumFavoriteType.MostFavorite;
     dataContext.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

It is not updating and showing error

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException'
>   occurred in 'A.Service.dll but was not handled in user code". "Row not
>   found or changed."

Comment: What kind of expression is byte(0)?

Comment: Actually product.Favorite will inject by enum, like product.Favorite =(byte)FavoriteType.MostFavorite

Comment: Please check your generated SQL statement, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045/what-can-i-do-to-resolve-a-row-not-found-or-changed-exception-in-linq-to-sql-o

Comment: Try to provide more details about the error by surrounding your code with try...catch and browse the error details.

Comment: "message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Row not found or changed.",
"exceptionType": "System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException",

Comment: @Markus Weninger There is no duplication in generated sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change entity class and added `PropertyChanged` of `Favorite` Property by following,

```
public class Products
{

  public byte Favorite { get; set; }
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Favorite;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this.Favorite != value))
                {

                    this.OnFavoriteChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Favorite");
                }
            }
        }

    partial void OnFavoriteChanging(byte value);

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

It works fine for me.