# "Row not found or changed" exception after SubmitChanges() on column entry update in MS Access 97' DB

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

### Edit

There is one thing that I hadn't considered; there are some Relationships specified on these tables.  Document is on the many side of a one-to-many with Folder, however it is also on the one-side of a one-to-many relationship with another table called `OCR`.  Do these relationships need to captured in my `Table` or `Column` attributes?  any help is greatly appreciated.

### Another dreaded "Row not found or changed" exception.

We're trying to update an existing entry in a table by change one column's value.  The tables we have are specified in code section **(1)**.  I'm getting to an instance of the `Document` Table through the code specified in code section **(2)** but that's where I hit an exception.

### Here are the things I have tried to resolve the issue:

i. tried marking every Column (in both Document and Folder) as `UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never`, As well as tweaking with `CanBeNull`

ii. tried to resolve changes after `SubmitChanges` call in part two using both `ChangeConflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges)` and `DataContext.Refresh(conflict, RefreshMode.KeepChanges)` on the `myContext.ChangeConflicts` set, and then do a re-`SubmitChanges`

iii. tried disabling the `EntityRef<Folder>` in `Document`

iv.  tried re-adding the `Document` table entry -- this failed because the entry does indeed exist

v. gently rocking back and forth, screaming myself hoarse (this actually helped a bit)

### Thanks!

**(1)**

```
    [Table(Name = "Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        [Column(Name="Folder_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Folder_ID;

        private EntityRef<Folder> folder;
        [Association(Storage = "folder", ThisKey = "Folder_ID", OtherKey = "Folder_ID")]

        public Folder Folder
        {
            get { return folder.Entity; }
            set { folder.Entity = value; }
        }
        [Column]
        public int Document_ID;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Image_ID;

        [Column]
        public string ImageName;

        [Column]
        public string ReasonForRejection;
    }

    [Table(Name = "Folder")]
    public class Folder
    {
        [Column(Name = "Folder_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Folder_ID;

        [Column(Name = "FolderName")]
        public string FolderName;
    }
```

**(2)**

```
 public void MarkRejectReasonForImageID(int id, string rejReason, string dbPath) 
 {
    // Create DataContext for MS Access '97 DB
    DataContext myContext = new DataContext(new OleDBConnection(CreateJET4_OleDBConnectionString(dbPath));

    // Add load options so that Folder entity is attached 
    DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<Document>(d => d.Folder);
    myContext.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
    // Make sure ObjectTracking is turned on
    myContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = true;
    myContext.Connection.Open();
    // Get Document from context matching input id
    Document doc = myContext.GetTable<Document>().Where(d => d.Image_ID == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    if(doc!=null) {
      // Mark matching reject reason on document
      doc.ReasonForRejection = rejReason;

      // Resubmit table changes
      myContext.SubmitChanges(); // <-- "Runtime Exception: Row not found or changed."

    }
    myContext.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try double checking the types as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/83999/430661 Edit: never mind, missed the fact that you tried that already

Comment: Normally I'd suggest some form of tracing to see the exact queries that are issued and deduce from there what the problems can be, but I realize Access doesn't really have a lot of facilities for this... perhaps you can still try something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188211.aspx#odc_4009c15_topic4 and get some more information though.